# Asking questions about facebook in superuser

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Official stance on Facebook questions on SU?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/721/official-stance-on-facebook-questions-on-su)

I wanted to ask a question about facebook in superuser only to discover that almost all questions tagged [facebook](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/facebook) have been closed.

What's the policy regarding asking user questions about websites (Wikipedia, Google, Gmail, etc) and social networks in particular (facebook, twitter).

I understand programming questions on facebook apps on StackOverflow are ok, as demonstrated by the large number of [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook) there, that are actively being asked and discussed.

This question regards specifically user questions, such as:

- How do I open a page?
- How do I block a user?
- How do I upload/delete/tag pictures/videos?
- How do I set my privacy settings to blah, blah, blah?

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30475/official-stance-on-facebook-questions-on-su

Comment: Also, make sure to see the update to the duplicate question.  Facebook does have an official area to post your questions.  I will admit, it too me a while to even find it.

Answer (score 2):

https://superuser.com/faq

> **What kind of questions can I ask here?**
>
> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - videogames or consoles
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - cellphones or mobile devices, except smartphones such as iPhone that interface with your computer
> - electronic devices or media players, except insofar as they interface with your computer

I recommended that someone start a [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) site for Facebook.

Comment: *Facebook* should start a SE site for Facebook!